# Magento - Event/observer code to associate configurable product image to its children, is not working

Tags: php, image, magento, events, product

I am moving our company site to Magento and have run into a snag with product images. We have 15k products, 80% of which are simple products with a configurable parent. We paid for a cart transfer, but newly created products show no image on the simple product. I would have to set them in each simple product, which would take far too long as there are 5 to 7 size related simple products per configurable.

I am looking to use the catalog_product_save_after event to write the images associated with the configurable over to each of its children.

My code is not working (I am pretty new to Magento) and I would appreciate any help anyone could offer.

Cden_Share.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cden_Share>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Cden_Share>
    </modules>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cden_Share>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Cden_Share>
            </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <models>
                <cden_share>
                        <class>Cden_Share_Model</class>
                </cden_share>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <cden_share>
                        <class>cden_share/observer</class>
                        <method>shareMainImages</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </cden_share>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>     
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And my Observer.php finally. I got this code from an answer on stackoverflow to a similar question about product bundles ([Magento - How to show the same images for product bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387286/magento-how-to-show-the-same-images-for-product-bundles)).

```
<?php

class Cden_Share_Model_Observer
{
    public function shareMainImages(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();         
if ($product->getTypeId() == "configurable")
      {
        $main_image = $product->getImage();
          if($main_image != "no_selection")

          {
                        $productTypeIns = $product->getTypeInstance(true);
                        $childIds = $productTypeIns->getChildrenIds($product->getId());
              $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product';
                            foreach ($childIds as $childId) 
                {
                foreach($childId as $_childId) 
                  {
                    $childProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_childId); 
                      if ($childProduct->getImage()=="no_selection")
                      {
                        $childProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($importDir.$main_image,array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'),false,false);
                        $childProduct->save();
                    }           
                }
            }
        }
            }
        }
 }
?>
```

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: — what's not working?  Is your observer method not be called, or is it being called but the code inside isn't doing what you want?

Comment: Sorry, Cden_Share is showing as enabled in System > Advanced, but other than that I can't see that it is doing anything. No images are shared, and looking at the database no change is made to the entries for the simple products. The files are in the right locations, so I am assuming there is something wrong with my observer code.

Comment: I figured out how to turn on debugging through index.php and now get this error when I try to save an item _Warning: include(Mage/Cden/Share/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/campus/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93_. I checked that line of code and found this '        return include $classFile;' at the end of the autoload function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at your error message

```
Warning: include(Mage/Cden/Share/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream
```

Magento's autoloader is trying to load your class file from the `Mage` package.  This usually indicates it can't find a base class name for the model `cden_share/observer`.  That is, Magento tries to instantiate the observer class

```
$observer = Mage::getMode('cden_share/observer');
```

and can't find a `cden_share` model group node in your configuration.  Take a look at your configuration, it appears you have this node, but it's in the wrong place.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cden_share>
                <class>Cden_Share_Model</class>
            </cden_share>
        </models>        
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <!-- ... -->
    </adminhtml>        
</config>
```

The `<models/>` node belongs under `<global/>`.

If you're still having trouble, after changing your configuration, some temporary debugging in [the following location](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6631/can-not-override-sales-resouce-model-collection-class/6664#6664) should tell you why Magento can't find the configuration node it's looking for.

Comment: That did it! I was unsure about the adminhtml vs. global, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I had to add in a condition for ($main_image != is_null) since most of the simple product's image will be set that way in the DB, but now when I try to use the Manage Product > Associated Products > 
Quick simple product creation tool the system hangs on product creation. I'm assuming that the Configurable needs to save and the Simple is not yet completely built, so it can't associate an image. Did I build in a race condition, and would making this module a button at the top of the product edit page be a good fix?

Comment: @MattTrueblood Sounds like a different question to me.  Also, when an ajax form "hangs" in Magento, it's usually (but not always) because an  exception has happened during the Ajax request, and Magento doesn't recover.

Comment: Thanks, I created another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449864/magento-retask-event-observer-module-into-a-button-at-the-top-of-the-admin-pro)